# Enable third-party cookies and site data for certain domains

Tags: google-chrome, cookies

I want `example.com` to be able to write and read **third-party cookies and site data** but no other domain may access any other domain's cookies and site data. It is only possible to globally enable/disable **third-party cookies and site data**.

[image: Chrome's Cookies Settings]

Ideally, I can even fine-tune access as in:

- `example.com` may access cookies and data of `web.example.com`
- `example.com` may access cookies of `elpmaxe.com`
- all other third-party access is blocked

Is there an extension that supports this? How to configure it? Open source preferred.

An incomplete workaround is to have a Chrome profile in which you:

- enable **third party cookies and site data**
- only visit example.com and the websites, of which it should be able to access their data
- accept that the other website will be able to read example.com's cookies and data

Comment: I too would love to know how to accomplish this. JIRA includes a side thing that connects to Harvest for logging time against issues, but that code uses a "third-party cookie". I definitely don't want to allow all third-party cookies access, only that one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that easily with [uMatrix](https://github.com/gorhill/uMatrix).

This free and open-source browser extension is available:

- [for Google Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/umatrix/ogfcmafjalglgifnmanfmnieipoejdcf), and all Chromium-based browsers (Chromium, Vivaldi...)
- [for Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en/firefox/addon/umatrix/)
- [for Opera](https://addons.opera.com/en/extensions/details/umatrix/)

Example:
Check the "Cookie" column on this following screenshot.

- Green color = cookie authorized
- Red color = cookie blocked

[image: umatrix panel]

Answer (score 5):

For me, the section "Sites that can always use cookies" worked:

[image]

I enabled the checkbox "All cookies, on this site only".

Comment: This is the right answer. Thanks :-)

Comment: How do I do this with group policy?  Google says to use this, but it doesn't do anything useful https://admx.help/?Category=Chrome&Policy=Google.Policies.Chrome::CookiesAllowedForUrls

Comment: @Arrow_Raider sorry, I don't know.